# Store Hardcoded JSON string to variable

Tags: c#, json

I'm having an issue storing this json string to a variable.  It's gotta be something stupid I am missing here

```
private string someJson = @"{
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "ErrorDetails": {
        "ErrorID": 111,
        "Description": {
            "Short": 0,
            "Verbose": 20
        },
        "ErrorDate": ""
    }
}";
```

Comment: Replace " with "" in the content

Comment: I think you just drank too much coffee... we've all been there...

Comment: And here's the relevant part of the friendly manual for good measure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: but why doesn't @ solve the ""'

Comment: Try to use ' instead of "

Comment: @ClarkKent it's not js man

Comment: clark I was gonna do that but yea I should have just done that  :)

Comment: If @ escaped a quote how would the compiler know where the string ends? It would be impossible to parse.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict the @ symbol escapes everything with the exception of the quote escape sequence: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Clark, I was thinking what verdesrobert was, that it's not JS but you know what?  I'm storing it as JSON so it's fine to have single quotes I think.  I'm not sure if the JavascriptSerializer cares when it attempts to deserialize it with single quotes, haven't tried, maybe it doesn't matter

Comment: I guess I'll just delete my correct answer since some idiot decided to downvote. This question is pretty bad anyway. You can have single quotes as I suggested in my answer and then you don't need to have a dozen escape characters in the string.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to escape the "'s if you use the @ symbol it doesn't allow the \ to be used as an escape after the first ". So the two options are:

don't use the @ and use \ to escape the "

```
string someJson = "{\"ErrorMessage\": \"\",\"ErrorDetails\": {\"ErrorID\": 111,\"Description\":{\"Short\": 0,\"Verbose\": 20},\"ErrorDate\": \"\"}}";
```

or use double quotes

```
string someJson =@"{""ErrorMessage"": """",""ErrorDetails"": {""ErrorID"": 111,""Description"": {""Short"": 0,""Verbose"": 20},""ErrorDate"": """"}}";
```

Comment: best way is to use `Json.net` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168701/exception-creating-json-with-linq)

Comment: yes, the simplest way just convert online https://tools.knowledgewalls.com/jsontostring

Comment: I Also wrote a converter that uses the double quotes syntax to escape JSON strings in c# https://json-to-c-sharp.ndolestudio.com/

Answer (score 22):

First things first, I'll throw this out there: It's for this reason in JSON blobs that I like to use single quotes.

But, much depends on how you're going to declare your `string` variable.

```
string jsonBlob = @"{ 'Foo': 'Bar' }";
string otherBlob = @"{ ""Foo"": ""Bar"" }";
```

...This is an ASCII-encoded string, and it should play nicely with single quotes.  You can use the double-double-quote escape sequence to escape the doubles, but a single quote setup is cleaner.  Note that \" won't work in this case.

```
string jsonBlob = "{ 'Foo': 'Bar' }";
string otherBlob = "{ \"Foo\": \"Bar\" }";
```

...This declaration uses C#'s default string encoding, Unicode.  Note that you have to use the slash escape sequence with double quotes - double-doubles will not work - but that singles are unaffected.

From this, you can see that single-quote JSON literals are unaffected by the C# string encoding that is being used.  This is why I say that single-quotes are better to use in a hardcoded JSON blob than doubles - they're less work, and more readable.

Comment: Using single quotes is okay and will most likely work but its not a good idea since it is not a part of the JSON standard.  The standard calls for double quotes.

Comment: Other platforms and linting tools won't accept single quotes. As an example, jQuery wouldn't parse json with single quotes last time I checked.

Comment: @Timigen. The .NET ecosystem itself has come to roost now and the newer `System.Text.Json` library doesn't like single quotes, unlike the older `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

Comment: System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '''' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'.

Answer (score 10):

Simple Approach is to copy the JSON to a .json file and read that file in the code

```
string jsonData = string.Empty;
jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"\UISettings.json");
```

Answer (score 7):

**A *Put the cart before the horse* solution** would be to serialize a anonymous class into a string:

```
var someJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
   new
    {
        ErrorMessage = "",
        ErrorDetails = new
        {
            ErrorID = 111,
            Description = new
            {
                Short = 0,
                Verbose = 20
            },
            ErrorDate = ""
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting from **C# 11** supported on .NET 7, it's possible to embed a JSON string without any modification by enclosing it in **triple quote characters**, a feature called *Raw string literal* ([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/raw-string-literal)). Related useful language feature is **StringSyntaxAttribute** that allows Visual Studio to recognize the string variable is a JSON string and highlight any typos. A sample:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Text.Json;

internal class Program
{
    [StringSyntax(StringSyntaxAttribute.Json)]
    private const string myCountry = """{"Name": "Slovakia", "CountryCode": 421}""";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _ = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Country>(myCountry);
    }

    class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem I ended up writing an open source online converter that takes a JSON string and spits out the C# excaped string with the double quotes syntax. So

```json
{ "foo":"bar"}
```

will be escaped into

```cs
var jsonString = @"{ ""foo"":""bar""}";
```

- https://json-to-c-sharp.ndolestudio.com
- https://github.com/AchoArnold/json-to-c-sharp

Comment: This worked great for a good-sized set of test data - thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

Writing JSON inline with c# in strings is a bit clunky because of the double quotes required by the JSON standard which need escaping in c# as shown in the other answers. One elegant workaround is to use c# dynamic and JObject from JSON.Net.

```
dynamic message = new JObject();
message.ErrorMessage = "";
message.ErrorDetails = new JObject();
message.ErrorDetails.ErrorId = 111;
message.ErrorDetails.Description = new JObject();
message.ErrorDetails.Description.Short = 0;

Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());

// Ouputs:
// { 
//   "ErrorMessage": "",
//   "ErrorDetails": {
//     "ErrorID": 111,
//     "Description": {
//       "Short": 0
// .....
```

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm.