# Exception creating JSON with LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I am trying to create JSON with the following code:

```
JArray jInner = new JArray("document");
JProperty jTitle = new JProperty("title", category);
JProperty jDescription = new JProperty("description", "this is the description");
JProperty jContent = new JProperty("content", content);
jInner.Add(jTitle);
jInner.Add(jDescription);
jInner.Add(jContent);
```

when I get to the `jInner.Add(jTitle)`, I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ValidateToken(JToken o, JToken existing)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken item, Boolean skipParentCheck)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object content, Boolean skipParentCheck)
```

Can anybody help and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If my answer isn't what you're looking for, please give an example of the JSON you're trying to produce.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't make sense to add a property to an array. An array consists of values, not key/value pairs.

If you want something like this:

```
[ {
  "title": "foo",
  "description": "bar"
} ]
```

then you just need an intermediate `JObject`:

```
JArray jInner = new JArray();
JObject container = new JObject();
JProperty jTitle = new JProperty("title", category);
JProperty jDescription = new JProperty("description", "this is the description");
JProperty jContent = new JProperty("content", content);
container.Add(jTitle);
container.Add(jDescription);
container.Add(jContent);
jInner.Add(container);
```

Note that I've removed the `"document"` argument from the `JArray` constructor call too. It's not clear why you had it, but I strongly suspect you don't want it. (It would have made the first element of the array the string `"document"`, which would be fairly odd.)