# How to serialize slack block? in C#

Tags: c#, json, slack

I made a template using Slack block kit builder

I read some data and fill eight parameters

in my C# code I have to use interpolated string and curly braces to supply the parameters {}. I also need to skip the braces by adding them twice.

but this is not recognized as correct json when I  make the post message call :

```
var data = new NameValueCollection();
data["token"] = token;
data["channel"] = channelName;
data["as_user"] = "true";           
data["text"] = postedMessage;
data["blocks"]=jsonstring; 
var client = new WebClient();
var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.co/api/chat.postMessage", "POST", data);
string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
Console.WriteLine(responseInString);
```

I understand the correct way is to represent these blocks as classes . I tried to follow the slack attachment representation but the blocks are more complex containing inner objects and not string variables as the attachment class . Appreciate your support to represent the blocks using easy syntax and correct json

Comment: Okay , I will go over the example. But will I be able  to include variables within my json string to fill the parameters?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But it can be tricky, because you will need to escape some characters the JSON way for this to work, e.g. special characters in UTF-8

Comment: see this for the official documentation on how that works for JSON: https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is that in C# single quotes only work for single characters. Here is how to properly escape double quotes and curly brackets of a JSON for hard-coded string constants.

### normal string constants

To properly escape the hard-coded JSON inside your code you need to add a backslash to each and every double quotes of your JSON string.

**Example**:

```
string someJson = "{\"ErrorMessage\": \"\",\"ErrorDetails\": {\"ErrorID\": 111,\"Description\":{\"Short\": 0,\"Verbose\": 20},\"ErrorDate\": \"\"}}";
```

There are other ways on how to do it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998177/store-hardcoded-json-string-to-variable) for a full overview of the solutions.

Btw. you will not need to escape curly brackets in this approach.

### interpolated string constants

With interpolated string you also need to escape the double quotes. But here it works by doubling them.

**Example**:

```
string someJson = "{\"ErrorMessage\": \"\",\"ErrorDetails\": {\"ErrorID\": 111,\"Description\":{\"Short\": 0,\"Verbose\": 20},\"ErrorDate\": \"\"}}";
```

For interpolated strings you will also need to escape the curly brackets. This works by doubling the escaped curly brackets, since the single curly brackets are used for interpolating.

**Example**:

```
var json = $@"{{""name"":""{name}""}}";
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91362/how-to-escape-braces-curly-brackets-in-a-format-string-in-net) for a full discussion on how to escape curly brackets.

Comment: I will add the backslash to  every double qoute but how do I manager the interpolation braces? String someJson =$ “" \attribute:\“{variable1} "

Comment: but if you must, you can escape the curley brackets too within an interpolated string. Let me add to the answer.

Comment: It worked. You have no idea how much I appreciate your support. Maybe I need to re-write the question to better address the issue. thank you so much really